# Why does resampling with Periods convert to DatetimeIndex in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(24, 4),
                 index=pd.period_range('1-2000', '12-2001', freq='M'),
                 columns=['Colorado', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Ohio'])
frame.resample('Q', how='mean').index
```

This works as it should, producing a `PeriodIndex`,

```
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q3', '2000Q4', '2001Q1', '2001Q2',
             '2001Q3', '2001Q4'],
            dtype='int64', freq='Q-DEC')
```

However, when I want to resample using a multiple of a base frequence,

```
frame.resample('2Q', how='mean').index
```

I get a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-03-31', '2000-09-30', '2001-03-31', '2001-09-30',
           '2002-03-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2Q-DEC')
```

Why does resampling with Periods in this case convert to DatetimeIndex in pandas? Is this behavior to be expected? Am I doing something wrong?
This is inconvenient because then I have to write

```
df = frame.resample('2Q', how='mean')
df.index = df.index.to_period('2Q')
df.index
```

to get

```
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q3', '2001Q1', '2001Q3', '2002Q1'], 
            dtype='int64', freq='2Q-DEC')
```

Comment: If you use the `kind='period'` parameter then you get `Warning: multiple of frequency -> timestamps` so this is the current expected behaviour. Looking at resample.py there is a comment saying `# Cannot have multiple of periods, convert to timestamp`. It's not obvious to me why.